# Explorer with Fabric v1.4 - Cannot GET at 8080

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-explorer

I have configured our Fabric network (v1.4) with Explorer (latest version).

- No errors in db log
- No application level errors
- Explorer syncing process is going on continuously for the network
- Able to view the updated data in DB
- http://localhost:8080/api-docs/  (Explorer Swagger) works fine.

However while accessing http://localhost:8080/ i am getting **Cannot GET /** error.

Though the Explorer works with Fabric 1.3, was the above one expected or an issue (I do not think so)?

Any thoughts are welcome!

**Edit 1:**

*Console Error* - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of http://localhost:8080/ **404** (Not Found)

Answer (score 1):

So, I found the answer to the problem - 
Weirdly the problem was it shows everywhere that it serves on localhost:8080 but after a lot of research found out that node js cannot serve static pages which hyperledger explorer is on port 8080.
So, needs to use "serve" to build and serve that page.

**Solution :**

```
$ cd ~/<YourPath>/blockchain-explorer/client
$ npm install
$ npm test -- -u --coverage 
$ npm run build
$ npm install -g serve
$ serve -s build
```

Now it will show you the output something like :

```
   ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                                                    │
   │   Serving!                                         │
   │                                                    │
   │   - Local:            http://localhost:5000        │
   │   - On Your Network:  http://160.33.244.178:5000   │
   │                                                    │
   │   Copied local address to clipboard!               │
   │                                                    │
   └────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

If you open up : http://localhost:5000 it will not show anything and in the network logs on inspect window will show you - **"control security policy violation".**

so use port 8080 instead like this :

```
- Local:            http://localhost:8080        │
- On Your Network:  http://160.33.244.178:8080
```

Also, you would need to start the hyperldger explorer server :

```
$ cd ~/<YourPath>/blockchain-explorer
$ ./start.sh
```

You will see login page with first network selected.

Use :

```
"adminUser" is the the admin user of the network, in this case it's fabric CA or an identity user.
"adminPassword" is the password for the admin user.
```

and you are in !

Answer (score -1):

That happened with me because the `npm rebuild` failed to create `build` in `blockchain-explorer/client` directory. I cleaned up the `node-modules` folder an re-ran the `npm install` followed by `npm run build` command. 
Make sure to stop explorer by running `./stop.sh` in home directory, kill the already running node process for this with pid (can be listed with `netstat -tulpn`) and that you are using the recommended version of node.
Once a build gets generated without any errors, run `./start.sh` again to see if the app comes up.